# Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' Error Code:1

Tags: android, android-studio

Hey I am pretty new with developing on Android using android-studio.

I added a onClick and ended up with this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /Users/home/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /Users/home/Documents/****/Android/MyApp/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/Users/home/Documents/****/Android/MyApp/app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
>     Error Code:
>       1

```
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option     to get more log output.
```

I tried removing some dependencies, reinstalled and updated everything but still doesnt work.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "myapp.com.example.home.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
  //  compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.+'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens cause you can´t have duplicate classes.

You must check you build, generated sources and projects, so you don´t include a *lib* more than once.

Also, different versions of the same *lib*, may also cause errors.